# openCV-2.4.9 'make' error

Tags: 14.04, opencv, cmake

I want to install openCV-2.4.9 on Jetson TK1. Environment of this is Ubuntu 14.04.
I refer to http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-opencv-2-4-9-ubuntu-14-04-13-10/

In this process I had the error message.

```
[ 14%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/__/dynamicuda/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_11'
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o.cmake:208 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/ubuntu/opencv-2.4.9/build/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/__/dynamicuda/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o


make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/__/dynamicuda/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_matrix_operations.cu.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 2):

you can modify the cmake command as below:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D CUDA_GENERATION=Kepler ..
```

This is because you install cuda in your system.You should make sure your architecture is Kepler to use this command.
I hope i can help you